# 54321 4321 321 1 in JavaScript using recursion

Tags: javascript, recursion, numbers

I have a problem about recursive in JavaScript.
This is my code when I use loop, but I want to use recursive.

```
function triangleNumber(num) {
       for(var i = num; i >= 1 ; i--){
           var str = ''
           for(var j = i; j >= 1; j--){
              str += j
           }
           console.log(str)
       }

    //DRIVER CODE
    console.log(triangleNumber(5));
    // 54321
    // 4321
    // 321
    // 21
    // 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this solution, where you build the string using the for loop appending numbers till you reach 1. Then you call the function recursively for the next smaller number`n - 1`:

```js
function triangleNumber(num) {
       if(num <= 0){ //Base case return if number reaches '0'
        return;
       }
       var str = ''
       for(var i = num; i >= 1; i--){
         str += i; //Create number string by appending successive decreasing value
       }  
       console.log(str);
       triangleNumber(num - 1) //Recursively call the function for the next lower number     
}
triangleNumber(5);
```

Comment: thank you bro, it works. and thanks again for your explanation

Comment: I'm sorry. I'm new here. What should I do to accept your answer ?

Answer (score 0):

Pretty straightforward :)

```js
function triangleNumber(num) {
    if(num<1) return;
    var str = '';
    for(var i = num; i >= 1 ; i--)  str += i;
    console.log(str);
    triangleNumber(num-1)
}

triangleNumber(5);
```